# Creating javascript object from simple object

Tags: javascript, object

Suppose i have this object

```
var io={"NAME":"Battery For Alarm Panel","CODE":"POWER MAX","OWN":"ONM"}
```

which i can access like below

```
 io['NAME'] or io['CODE'] etc.
```

But if want to create another object then how i can access `obj` like below code is not working with error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`

```
       detailObj=
        {
            io['NAME']:
            {
                io['CODE']:
                {
                    io['OWN']:"12"
                }
            }
        }
```

What changes i need to made in `io` object to create `detailObj`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't declare an object like that, using variables inside of the object declaration for the property names. You'll have to create the object like this:

```
detailObj = {};
detailObj[io['NAME']] = {};
detailObj[io['NAME']][io['CODE']] = {};
detailObj[io['NAME']][io['CODE']][io['OWN']] = "12";
```

Comment: but i have to loop to push this created object to a new object

Comment: getting this object created `"details":{"undefined":{"undefined":{"undefined":"2"}}}}`

Comment: If that is what you are getting, the you must not have defined `io`.

Answer (score 1):

The `object["property"]` syntax is meant to access an object properties and doesn't have anything to do with the syntax for object creation. If you want to access an object several levels down, follow the example below:

```
var basket = {
    box: { 
          mobilePhone: "mobilePhone"
         }
}
```

To access mobilePhone property of basket you would use: `basket.box.mobilePhone` or `basket["box"]["mobilePhone"]`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use JSON syntax with a dynamic key.

You have many solutions :

```
var detailObj = {};
detailObj[io.NAME] = {};
detailObj[io.NAME][io.CODE] = {};
detailObj[io.NAME][io.CODE][io.OWN] = "12";
```

or

```
var detailObj = {};
var detailObjNAME = (detailObj[io.NAME] = {});
var detailObjCODE = (detailObjName[io.CODE] = {});
detailObjCODE[io.OWN] = "12";
```

or

```
var detailObj = {};
((detailObj[io.NAME] = {})[io.CODE] = {})[io.OWN] = "12";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var io={"NAME":"Battery For Alarm Panel","CODE":"POWER MAX","OWN":"ONM"};

var detailObj = {};
detailObj[io['NAME']] = {};
detailObj[io['NAME']][io['CODE']] = {};
detailObj[io['NAME']][io['CODE']][io['OWN']] = "12";
```

Comment: giving this result "details":{"undefined":{"undefined":{"undefined":"2"}}}