# adding javascript object in existing object

Tags: javascript, object

I was thinking that i know much about `javascript` but i must have to admit i know nothing.
i have been trying to create a custom object but still seems no where.

```
var currentline=[
        {"NAME":"Battery For Alarm Panel","CODE":"POWER MAX","OWN":"ONM"},
        {"NAME":"Fire Alarm Panel","CODE":"SANA SERVICES","OWN":"ONM"}...
       ]
```

Through help of  [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557796/creating-javascript-object-from-simple-object) i'm able to create following object

```
   // skipping main loop code for brevity
   detailObj=[];
   loop{
     singleObj = {};
     singleObj[currentline['NAME']] = {};
     singleObj[currentline['NAME']][currentline['CODE']] = {};
     singleObj[currentline['NAME']][currentline['CODE']][currentline['OWN']] = value;
     detailObj.push(singleObj);
   }
```

AND get the following `detailObj`

```
       [
        {"Battery For Alarm Panel":{"POWER MAX":{"ONM":7}}},
        {"Fire Alarm Panel":{"SANA SERVICES":{"ONM":8}}}
       ]
```

**how i can `push` an object into object despite into array and could get following object?**

```
       {
       "Battery For Alarm Panel":{"POWER MAX":{"ONM":7}},
       "Fire Alarm Panel":{"SANA SERVICES":{"ONM":8}}
       }
```

**is there any function to add object in the object?**

Comment: In your prototype code you iterate currentline but currentline is an Array which contain Objects. So a numeric loop is necessary and Then you can access it via  currentline[index].NAME

Comment: yes i know; but ijust has simplyfy it. i just to know the way to add object in the object

Comment: Please post a working example then it's easier to understand your implementation and support you for the changes which are required to match your goal

Comment: if i would have post a complete example it might have been a complete mess and might not able to get the early answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `currentline` is like this

```
var currentline = [{
    "NAME": "Battery For Alarm Panel",
    "CODE": "POWER MAX",
    "OWN": "ONM",
    "VALUE": 7
}, {
    "NAME": "Fire Alarm Panel",
    "CODE": "SANA SERVICES",
    "OWN": "ONM",
    "VALUE": 8
}];
```

Simply change the `detailObj` an object and instead of pushing, assign `NAMES` values as keys, like this

```
var detailObj = {};    // An object, not an array
currentline.forEach(function(line) {
    detailObj[line.NAME] = {};
    detailObj[line.NAME][line.CODE] = {};
    detailObj[line.NAME][line.CODE][line.OWN] = line.VALUE;
});
console.log(detailObj);
# { 'Battery For Alarm Panel': { 'POWER MAX': { ONM: 7 } },
#   'Fire Alarm Panel': { 'SANA SERVICES': { ONM: 8 } } }
```

Comment: @MuhammadHaseebKhan Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)