# how to add object within an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Suppose we have the following object :

```
var possibility ={
object 1
object 2
object 3
};
```

how can i add 4th object within "possibility" object,structure of that 4th object is like :

```
var status = {
name : "lalala",
text : "blabla"
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding javascript object in existing object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22576816/adding-javascript-object-in-existing-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will assign to the property of an object, which is not defined,it will create a new property and assign to it the value

```
possibility['status'] = {
   name : "lalala",
   text : "blabla"
};
```

or

```
possibility.status = {
       name : "lalala",
       text : "blabla"
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a property by addressing it as a property.

```
possibility.status = status;
```